# MySQL Trigger only runs partially

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I am trying to implement a trigger which transfers multiple records from 4 different tables to another set of 4 tables (denoted by the _history suffix) which have the same schema.

The trigger is as follows

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger shift_to_history
    before update on event_ledger
    for each row
   begin
        declare id,event_id,communication_number,communication_flag,slot_number,room_id,status_level,prev_status_level int default 0;
        declare msg text;
        declare req_date,end_date,start_date date;
        declare purpose varchar(30);
        declare misc_ledger_cursor cursor for select * from misc_ledger where event_id = old.event_id;
        declare resource_communication_cursor cursor for select * from resource_communication where event_id = old.event_id;
        declare slots_and_details_cursor cursor for select * from slots_and_details where event_id = old.event_id;
        declare event_communication_cursor cursor for select * from event_communication where event_id = old.event_id;
        insert into event_ledger_history values(old.event_id,old.event_name,old.description,old.username,old.start_date,old.end_date);
        open misc_ledger_cursor;
        begin
            declare finished int default 0;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
            misc_ledger_transfer: loop
                fetch misc_ledger_cursor into event_id,communication_number,req_date,msg,communication_flag;
                if finished = 1 then
                    leave misc_ledger_transfer;
                end if;
                insert into misc_ledger_history values (event_id,communication_number,req_date,msg,communication_flag);
            end loop misc_ledger_transfer;
        end;
        close misc_ledger_cursor;
        delete from misc_ledger where event_id = old.event_id;


        open resource_communication_cursor;
        begin
            declare finished int default 0;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
            resource_coms_transfer: loop
                fetch resource_communication_cursor into event_id,msg,communication_number,communication_flag;
                if finished = 1 then
                    leave resource_coms_transfer;
                end if;
                insert into resource_communication_history values (event_id,msg,communication_number,communication_flag);
                delete from resource_communication where id = event_id;
            end loop resource_coms_transfer;
        end;
        close resource_communication_cursor;


        open event_communication_cursor;
        begin
            declare finished int default 0;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
            event_coms_transfer: loop
            fetch event_communication_cursor into event_id,msg,communication_number,communication_flag;
            if finished = 1 then
                leave event_coms_transfer;
            end if;
            insert into event_communication_history values (event_id,msg,communication_number,communication_flag);
        end loop event_coms_transfer;
        end;
        close event_communication_cursor;
        delete from event_communication where event_id = old.event_id;


        open slots_and_details_cursor;
        begin
            declare finished int default 0;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
            slots_and_details_transfer: loop
                fetch slots_and_details_cursor into id,event_id,slot_number,room_id,start_date,end_date,status_level,prev_status_level,purpose,msg;
                if finished = 1 then
                    leave slots_and_details_transfer;
                end if;
                insert into slots_and_details_history values (id,event_id,slot_number,room_id,start_date,end_date,status_level,prev_status_level,purpose,msg);
            end loop slots_and_details_transfer;
         end;
        close slots_and_details_cursor;
        delete from slots_and_details where event_id = old.event_id;
    end//

DELIMITER ;
```

The Trigger runs only till

```
insert into event_ledger_history values(old.event_id,old.event_name,old.description,old.username,old.start_date,old.end_date);
```

After which it does not do anything.The MySQL Terminal gives a success message but the desired output is not achieved. ie The remaining history tables are till empty (the ones which use the cursor).

I reffered to  [MySQL stored procedure, handling multiple cursors and query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995189/mysql-stored-procedure-handling-multiple-cursors-and-query-results) but did not receive favorable results.

Comment: Do your declared variables have the same name as table columns? If so change them.

Comment: okay will try it

Comment: Also, there doesn't seem to be a reason to use cursors here. You can simply do `ìnsert... select ... where ...` (the where containing your condiiton from the cursor) instead of `insert ... values (...)` for each row.

Comment: Nope doesn't work

Comment: Yes but our academic project specifically requires the usage of triggers and cursors in the same block.

Comment: You aren't going to get much help simply posting non working code. You can improve this question by adding table definitions, sample data and an example update statement (all as text in the question). AND do you really want to do this FOR EACH ROW in a multi row update?